# Git view file names in objects/pack/pack-hash.pack

Tags: git

I committed and pushed large temporary files to a git server by mistake. On the git server, I reverted the last commit using the commands I found by Google searching, and its web interface, the number of commits is reduced by one, and that last commit is gone.

Still, it seems the data size on the server is not reduced. I did run those "prune" and "reflog" commands. On the server, there are a single large "pack" file and an "idx" file. I ran `git verify-pack -v <file name>.idx`, lots of data were shown but each line was cryptic like

> [Hash code] blob [number]  [number] [number]

So, I don't know what they are. Can I see original file names like "program.cs", so that I could see if the temporary files still exist in the repository?

Comment: *On the git server, I reverted the last commit using the commands I found by Google searching ...* But we don't know what those commands were, and can't guess as there are many conflicting instructions you could find this way. Meanwhile, it sounds like you're constructing a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question asked: *objects* do not have file names.  They're just *objects*.

Commits store files, but they do so indirectly.  Each commit object has exactly one reference to one *tree* object.  A tree object, in Git, consists of a series of records, with each record containing:

- a *mode*, which is a text string representing an octal number, such as `100755`, `100644`, `40000`, and so on;
- a path-name component: a binary (but generally valid UTF-8) string of varying length that does not contain either `/` or a NUL byte, followed by one NUL byte; and
- a hash ID (in binary, 20 bytes long).

A `mode` of `40000` indicates that the hash ID in the record is that of another tree object, so the hash ID must be the hash of another tree object (or the repository is broken).  Other modes imply other hash ID purposes, in which case the hash ID is generally that of a blob.  There is one other special case: mode `160000` represents a *gitlink* and indicates that the entry provides the hash ID to expect, and to `git checkout`, from a submodule.

Hence, blob ID *B* can represent multiple different file path names.  Those file names are constructed by concatenating the path-name segments in each tree object with that in the final mode-`100755` or mode-`100644` blob object in the series of objects that led to finding the final object.

That is, suppose commit *C<sub>a</sub>* has as its top level tree hash ID *T<sub>1</sub>* which refers to tree *T<sub>2</sub>* by name `d1`, and then *T<sub>2</sub>* refers to blob *B<sub>h</sub>* by name `f1`.  Then blob *B<sub>h</sub>* represents, *in this commit*, the file `d1/f1`.  But suppose commit *C<sub>b</sub>* has tree *T<sub>3</sub>* which refers to tree *T<sub>4</sub>* by name `d2`, and *T<sub>4</sub>* refers to *B<sub>h</sub>* by name `f2`.  Then blob *B<sub>h</sub>* represents the file `d2/f2` in commit *C<sub>b</sub>*.  If commit *C<sub>c</sub>* has a top level tree *T<sub>5</sub>* that refers to *B<sub>h</sub>* with name `f3`, commit *C<sub>c</sub>* stores the same file contents under the name `f3` (with no sub-folder).

Object persistence, in a repository, is a function of a bunch of rules whose primary driver is *reachability*.  See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) for the definition of reachability.  An unreachable object will (usually, eventually) be removed—but additional rules prevent deleting unreachable *loose* objects for some time, so that Git can create temporary objects and eventually—within the time period—*make* them reachable and thus permanent (or as permanent as they stay reachable).

Objects inside a pack simply cannot be deleted at all.  However, pack files containing many useless objects can, in general, be *re-packed* into new (and different) pack files; or they can be exploded into individual loose objects.  Once an old pack file is no longer needed—because all of its objects are available as loose objects or in a superseding pack—it can be discarded, but a `.keep` file for a pack file will prevent it from being discarded.  Git itself does not create `.keep` files: they are meant for humans who are fiddling with pack files directly (for whatever purposes).

The `git gc` command is the wrapper that is generally responsible for creating and maintaining pack files and for cleaning out aged-out, unreferenced loose objects.  It runs other internal Git commands, including `git reflog expire`, `git repack`, and `git prune`, to achieve this result.